# Схема сложного предложения

Tags: синтаксис, члены-предложения, сложное-предложение

"Может показаться странным, но ему нужны не только эти драгоценности да купюры в сто рублей, но и ваше мнение об этой книге". Пожалуйста, помогите составить схему этого предложения. Например: [ ], а [ ], ( ).

Comment: Если известен алгоритм, можете начать составление. Иначе вопрос останется без ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Может показаться странным**, но ему **нужны** **не только** эти **драгоценности да купюры** в сто рублей, **но и** ваше **мнение** об этой книге.

Это сложносочиненное предложение (ССП). Первое предложение неполное (это может показаться странным).

Во втором предложении распространенное подлежащее, два сочинительных союза: союз НЕ ТОЛЬКО...НО И, союз ДА=И).

Схема: [ ], но [ ].

Стилистическая неточность: повтор слова НО.

Comment: И еще одна стилистическая неточность: ему **нужно** ваше менение. Корректней: ему **важны** не только эти драгоценности да купюры в сто рублей, но и ваше мнение об этой книге.

Comment: У Розенталя: при союзах не только... но и, не столько... сколько и др. (содержащих оттенок противопоставления) сказуемое обычно согласуется с ближайшим из однородных подлежащих. У нас это мн. число, поэтому "ему нужны..." А какая (грамматическая) разница: нужны или важны?

Comment: Мне кажется, так не говорят: "Мне нужно ваше мнение", а говорят: "Мне нужно знать ваше мнение" или "Ваше мнение важно для меня".

Comment: Точнее, так говорят (к сожалению), но писать так  не следует.

Comment: Скорее всего, Вы правы.